# Httpd Misconfiguration of certificate's CN and virtual name

Tags: ssl, centos7, httpd, 500-error, openstack-horizon

I'm deploying openstack on CentOS7 and every services and modules deployed well.

but When I type `http://<controller-ip>/dashboard` , after few minutes, error message 500 `"Internal Server Error"` appears.
I'd checked `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and saw the error message is:

> [Mon Oct 09 10:05:55.743509 2017] [:error] [pid 27541] Misconfiguration of certificate's CN and virtual name. The certificate CN has localhost4.localdomain4. We expected controller as virtual name.

my /etc/hosts content is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.1.79.116     controller
192.168.2.22    controller
192.168.2.21    compute01
```

updated:
By following these links, still I have problem that mentioned above:

```
https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-centos
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-httpd-secure-server.html
https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/identity-certificates-for-pki.html
https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/openstack-ansible/ocata/app-advanced-config-sslcertificates.html
```

now I'm getting confused and I don't know what should I do.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the TLS certificate is the problem it might be because **1)** you connect with   `http://<controller-ip>/` where you are expected to use `httpS` **2)**  you are expected to connect to `httpS://<controller-hostname>/` rather than the IP-address **3)** your system is configured reference itself with the hostname `controller` and that name is not configured in the TLS certifcate you are using.

Comment: @HBruijn thanks for your recommendations, but 1)when I use https, again internal error occurs.2)I exactly enter http(s)://10.1.79.116/dashboard 3)how can I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug introduced by a package upgrade from Centos (I think from Centos 7.4 series). In order to solve it we need to change our "`/etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack-dashboard.conf`" file to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess dashboard
WSGIProcessGroup dashboard
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/django.wsgi
Alias /dashboard/static /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart httpd: `systemctl restart httpd`.

The missing item is: `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`

Comment: Thanks!  For me, I had the `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` line, but it was in one of the `<Directory>` blocks.  Moving that line out of the block worked